# Two Gaussian random variables $X,Y$ are uncorrelated if and only if they are independent?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let me first introduce the definition of Gaussian I came across

> A one dimensional random variable $\Gamma$ is Gaussian iff it has the characteristic function
>   $$\mathbb{E}[e^{i \xi \Gamma}]=e^{im\xi-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 \xi^2}$$
>   for some real numbers $m \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\sigma \geq 0$.

Now the question I have is, if $X,Y$ are two real-valued random variables which are Gaussian, and $Cov(X,Y)=0$, i.e. they are uncorrelated, how do I use the above definition to see that they are independent?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: For a counterexample, let $P(Z = 1) = P(Z = -1) = 1/2$, let $X$ be a standard normal random variable independent of $Z$ and let $Y = ZX$. $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated but not independent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that, we require the two random variables to be *jointly Gaussian* for the result to hold (it is possible that two random variables are Gaussian but not jointly Gaussian). Also, I shall work with density functions instead of characteristic function for simplicity (you can deduce the density from characteristic function, and vice versa). For notation purpose, I denote the random vector by $\left(X_1,X_2\right)$.

The joint probability density function of a bivariate normal distribution is given by
$$f_{X_1,X_2}\left(x_1,x_2\right)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_1\sigma_2\sqrt{1-\rho^2}} \times \exp{\left[-\frac{\left\{\left(\frac{x-\mu_1}{\sigma_1}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y-\mu_2}{\sigma_2}\right)^2-2\rho\left(\frac{x-\mu_1}{\sigma_1}\right)\left(\frac{y-\mu_2}{\sigma_2}\right)\right\}}{2\left(1-\rho^2\right)}\right]}$$
Now, $Cov(X_1,X_2)=0 \Leftrightarrow \rho=0$. Putting $\rho=0$ the joint density function reduces to
\begin{align*}
f_{X_1,X_2}\left(x_1,x_2\right)&=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_1\sigma_2} \times \exp{\left[-\frac{\left\{\left(\frac{x-\mu_1}{\sigma_1}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y-\mu_2}{\sigma_2}\right)^2\right\}}{2\left(1-\rho^2\right)}\right]}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sigma_1\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu_1}{\sigma_1}\right)^2\right\} \times \frac{1}{\sigma_2\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{y-\mu_2}{\sigma_2}\right)^2\right\}
\end{align*}

Since, we can factor out the joint density function in the form $g(x) \times h(y)$ (which automatically are the respective marginal densities), we conclude that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent.